# Extract certain words from string

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

in a column "Prod" and under this column I have words like

```
"GLASS VERT TAB 10"
"GLASS ROUGE LAB 12"
"GLASS JAUNE VERT RAB"
```

My output should be

```
"GLASS VERT"
"GLASS ROUGE"
"GLASS JAUNE VERT"
```

I need words before TAB|LAB|RAB in snowflake. I was trying
[REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/regexp_substr_all) but not getting it

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(PROD,'^(.+)TAB|LAB|RAB') as AB
```

but getting:

```
"GLASS VERT TAB"
"GLASS ROUGE LAB"
"GLASS JAUNE VERT"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can supply extra parameters to return the first group, which in your case holds the substring you want to extract

```
set str='GlASS VERT TAB 10';
select regexp_substr($str,'(.+) (TAB|LAB|RAB)', 1, 1, 'e');
```

Comment: only woks for TAB not for LAB or RAB. Any alternative?

Comment: @Rumi Sorry I missed the parenthesis on the second group. Try again

Answer (score 0):

If all your data like the examples in your question, you can use `REGEXP_REPLACE` to remove numbers and `LAB,RAB,TAB`

```
select REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(Prod,'[0-9]'), '\\s+(LAB|RAB|TAB)\\b') from myTable;
```

First replace removes the numbers and second one replaces `LAB,RAB,TAB`

Tested with

```
with myTable(Prod) as (
select * from (values
('GLASS VERT TAB 10'), 
('GLASS ROUGE LAB 12'), 
('GLASS JAUNE VERT RAB'))
)
select REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(Prod,'[0-9]'), '\\s+(LAB|RAB|TAB)\\b')
from myTable
```

Result

```
PROD
________________
GLASS VERT 
GLASS ROUGE 
GLASS JAUNE VERT
```

Comment: Hi, actually "GLASS VERT TAB 10" this is "GLASS VERT TAB 10 MG ORAL" and the last three words are inconsistent through out the data. Any suggestion?

Comment: Your requirement is not clear, you need to give a representative sample from your data set and lay out what is the requirement. Do you need to keep `MG ORAL` part? Do you only need what's before LAB,TAP,RAP?